# Does React-Redux update twice on connected components with ownProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

```js
const ConnectedComponent1 = connect(
  (state) => {return {options: state.option}}
)((props)=> {return (<Component2 options={props.options}/>)})

const Component2 = (props) => {
  const children = props.options.map(option=>{
    return (<ConnectedComponent3 option={option}/>)
  })
  return children
}

const ConnectedComponent3 = connect(
  (state, ownProps) => {return {optionB: state.options[ownProps.option.otherOptionId]}}
)((props)=> {return (<div>{props.option.id}{props.optionB.id}</div>)})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Lets say if I have this

So since Connect() is bound to the store update call, when the state updates does ConnectedComponent 2 updates twice? Once from the binding to the store update, and once from receiving new props?

If it does update twice which one happens first?

Comment: Can you share your example as JSX?

Comment: Updated my question!